# HttpPost works in localhost but not after publishing on server

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I created two methods in `mvc` `HttpGet` and `HttpPost` with same name. I post datea in `post` method it is working on my `localhost` visual studio. But when when i upload on the server it is not working. It is showing me `200` `ok status` response message, but the model list is `null`

What is the solution

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    list ml = new list();
    ml.test = UserDataList;
    ml.spfilterreport = enqList;

    return View(ml);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(Data DD)
{
    list ml = new list();
    ml.test = UserDataList;
    ml.spfilterreport = enqList;

    return View(ml);
}

<form name="myForm" action="~/Home/Index" method="post" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
    <div class="row" style="padding: 20px;background: white;margin-top: 6px;">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <p>From Date: <input type="text" id="FromDate" name="FromDate" required></p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <p>To Date: <input type="text" id="ToDate" name="ToDate" required></p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <p><input type="submit" id="btnFilter" name="btnFilter" value="Filter" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" /></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: `action="~/Home/Index"` localhost:8080 will be working however myapp.com/someFolder/  wont work, because it will be routed myapp.com/Home/Index

Comment: action="/Home/Index" this also not working . Html.Beginform also not working on server

Comment: Have you tried converting form action url to action='@Url.Action("Index","Home")'? This will generate a fully qualified url